# Simple d3 line not working with Angular 8

Tags: angular, d3.js, angular-material

I have a super simple line chart I'm trying to put inside my angular application. For whatever reason, it's throwing an error in visual studio code on this line:

```
.attr("d", line);
```

I've seen some solutions when researching but none of them have worked for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
(local var) line: d3.Line<LineDataType>
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(name: string, value: null): Selection<SVGPathElement, { date: string; value: number; }, HTMLElement, any>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Line<LineDataType>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(name: string, value: string | number | boolean): Selection<SVGPathElement, { date: string; value: number; }, HTMLElement, any>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Line<LineDataType>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | boolean'.
      Type 'Line<LineDataType>' is not assignable to type 'true'.
  Overload 3 of 4, '(name: string, value: ValueFn<SVGPathElement, { date: string; value: number; }, string | number | boolean>): Selection<SVGPathElement, { date: string; value: number; }, HTMLElement, any>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Line<LineDataType>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<SVGPathElement, { date: string; value: number; }, string | number | boolean>'.
      Types of parameters 'data' and 'datum' are incompatible.
        Type '{ date: string; value: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'LineDataType[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2769)
```

```
drawChart2() {
    $("#chart2").empty()
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 100
      },
      width = $("#chart-2").innerWidth() - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = $("#chart-2").innerHeight() - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#chart2").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = [{
      date: "2013-04-28",
      value: 135.98
    }, {
      date: "2013-04-29",
      value: 147.49
    }, {
      date: "2013-04-30",
      value: 127.49
    }];

    var line = d3.line<LineDataType>()
      .x(function(d) {return x(d.date);})
      .y(function(d) {return y(d.value);});

    // Add X axis --> it is a date format
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        let temp;
        temp = d;
        return temp.date;
      }))
      .range([0, width]);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return +d.value;
      })])
      .range([height, 0]);
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Add the line
    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line);
  }
```

Comment: typescript interfaces for d3 are not very correct, because it is very complex to make it 100% right. I believe that is the situation where you should use any. `.attr('d', line as any)` should compile and work well

Comment: @Andrei, so that worked but I'm not seeing the line in the actual chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the line to this allowed the code to compile

```
.attr('d', line as any)
```